# "Partially modal" forms in MDI app

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, mdi

I've got an MDI application. The user can open different non modal forms, for instance form A and form B. On form A there is a button which opens another form (let's say form C) and the same goes for form B (a button opening form D). What I'm trying to achieve is to have C blocking A and D blocking B. 
ShowDialog doesn't work because it blocks the whole app, so I tried to disable form A, and then loop with a while on a boolean which is set to false when C is closed (i.e.: while (blocked) Application.DoEvents();). In the following lines of code I re-enable A and then use the result obtained from C. 
It seems to work, but if I open C from A and then D from B, A is blocked by both C and D and not only by D. 
Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end solved it this way: 
in the method of A that opens C I 
 
1. disable form A 
2. create an instance of C (and store it in a field of A if I will need some of its data after C has been closed)
3. attach a method cClosed defined in class A to event FormClosed of the instance of C 
4. open form C

In the method cClosed I:
1. reenable form A 
2. do whatever I need after the closing of C  
3. clear the field containing C (if present)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to simulate what you want like this:

1. When A opens C, keep that reference in the A class (not inside some method, but to be visible to other methods)
2. When form A receives Activate event, then check if C is visible - if yes, focus it instead.

Similar goes for B-D, and whatever combination...

Comment: The same effect could be achieved by disabling A, attaching to the closing event of C a method of A that re-enable it and then show C. But this would prevent me from using the result obtained from the use of C. I could have it used in the re-enabling method of A, but I'd rather avoid this since I should replace the existing opening instructions thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Form.Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) to force a sort of modality. For example, when D is blocking B and the user selects (activates/sets focus to) B you could call Form.Activate on D. It's not quite modal but would enforce your Form-to-Form relationships. Of course when there is no D to block B you would not call Activate. This approach would also rid of the need to use [DoEvents](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) since no Form would ever really be locked.

Comment: The same effect could be achieved by disabling A, attaching to the closing event of C a method of A that re-enable it and then show C. But this would prevent me from using the result obtained from the use of C. I could have it used in the re-enabling method of A, but I'd rather avoid this since I should replace the existing opening instructions thousands of times.